# HTML/CSS - [shopify (brooklyn theme)] I can change sizes/colors in HTML but want to do it in CSS

Tags: html, css, shopify

Objective: The original theme code has a box that says "SAVE $XYZ" around each collection of products that are on sale. I want to edit it to look like

$ABC

SAVE $XYZ

but with $ABC being the retail price in strikethrough, in larger font size, a different color. 
I was able to do this in HTML but people always shun that for some reason so I want to learn how to do it in CSS.

Here's where the code can be found

ASSETS - theme.scss.liquid -- line 2979 to 3009

SNIPPETS - product-grid-item.liquid --line 41

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there are some missing information to help. Try to inspect the element and search for a CSS class or ID. With this information you can search in your theme.scss.liquid to edit the style.

[image]